# How to secure the password while it being sent using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, security

I'm trying to keep user's password secured, but I noticed that the header information send while submitting the form is visible to everyone. Is it secure or is there a way to keep it secure? I know how to add md5 to the password in JS, but MD5 isn't secure anymore and I can't add a salt with JS because everyone can find out what the salt is. So what are you suggesting to do? I think that soon I'll have a SSL to my website (https://), **but I not sure**, so I need another way to keep the communication safe. And even if I'll have an a SSL, so it is from the business plan of HostGator, and if I'm not mistaken, **the SSL doesn't work on mobile**. (The form sent via post using AJAX).

Comment: Even if you encrypt it on client side, it's still JS. Anybody can see what you're doing.

Comment: What makes you think SSL doesn't work on mobile?  No matter whether it's sent though GET, POST, AJAX, or any combination of them, it's readable unless sent over SSL.

Comment: @Bibhas exactly! That what I'm asking! How to secure the sending itself, not when it is already in the server? I guess that a strong hashing, even if the hacker know how did it hashed, it will keep the password safe while they "on the way" to the server, but I don't know a very strong hashing in JS (or JQ)

Comment: @VladGincher, this is what transport layer security (SSL or TLS) is for.

Comment: We had a similar situation where we need to pass the password over AJAX. The solution we used we created a temp table in the DB with 2 fields `hash_key` and `password`, so before sending the password over AJAX we do an insert into that table, and the hash_key we generate for that row using sha1() and that hash key is passed over AJAX for pass. In the server side coding use that hash to get the password from DB temp table, do the process and then delete the row. May be its not the best way but could not find something better then.

Comment: http://tonyarcieri.com/whats-wrong-with-webcrypto

Comment: @zero298 I know that SSL works on mobile, but the SSL that HostGator offers to the business plan doesn't. And again, I know that Post itself isn't secure, but is it will be hashed strongly on the user side (JS), so the hacker will see just  SEFGSEFGJEGN!@FqfQ#F$ and not the password itself. But I don't know how to hash it strongly. Facebook and Google working also without SSL (in the options you can set the SSL to OFF), and I guess that the password still secure.

Comment: @VladGincher That's a terrible idea.  it's called a replay attack.  If they get ahold of the packets even if the password is encrypted they can just send the encrypted password along.  don't assume a hacker will use your interface, they'll go right around it.  SSL/TLS is the only way to secure the sending of a password

Comment: @VladGincher: Without SSL, you cannot be secure, _period_.  The attacker can modify your hashing code to send him the password first.  You **need** to use a decent host that supports full SSL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AJAX is irrelevant.

The only way to secure your login page is to use SSL or TLS, which work fine on modern mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I also think HTTPS is already available in most mobile browsers. But if you're sure it isn't in your situation, you could consider a public key cryptography js library. [pidCrypt](https://www.pidder.de/pidcrypt/) springs to mind. But **only** if it's really necessary, it's rather overkill in most cases I think.

Comment: No.  Not not use browser-side cryptography without SSL.  It will give you exactly zero security.

Comment: To clarify, without SSL, you cannot prevent an attacker from changing your JS code in-flight to send him a copy of the plaintext first.

Comment: But you have to agree it's **more** secure than just sending the plaintext password. At least you're safe from traffic sniffing. Or am I not seeing something?

Comment: @SimonPlus you are not seeing something.  What is the difference on the server side between receiving the plaintext password or the encrypted password?  As far as the server is concerned, that encrypted password **is the password**.  So whether you get the plaintext or the encrypted version is of no concern to the server.  The user may have different feelings towards those two scenarios, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can download from here http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha512.html the sha512.js and then declare a function like this:

```
function formhash(form, password)
{
    $(form).append('<input name="p" type="hidden" >');
    var p = $('input[name="p"]');
    p.val(hex_sha512(password.val()));
    password.val('');

    return p.val();
}
```

so afterwards you can send data to your server with ajax like:

```
var dataObj = {
    'username': $('input[name="username"]').val(),
    'password': formhash($('.form-signin'), $('input[name="password"]'))
};
```

and your password will be sent already encrypted. Of course you should use https to your login form page too.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile applications, and browsers, support SSL - that is not your issue here.  If your host does not support SSL, then you need to switch off of it.

Client side crypto will provide you with no additional security.  It might provide you user with additional security.

All of the attacks that could be used to get the password from the client could also be used to get the hashed or encrypted password from the client - your system would except that value, not knowing that it was not the user's browser that generated it.  So client side crypto is not going to provide your site with any additional security.

The perspective is different if you are trying to protect your user.  By using client-side crypto, you could make the argument that you never know the user's password, protecting the user in the event of a breach of your systems.  Your system would still be compromised, but all of the other systems that use that password would not be.

For an authentication mechanism, you need Transport Layer Security, there is pretty much no way around it.